# Joomla! component K2 - store form data to database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla-k2

I have created custom array form for k2 item.

```
<div id="dynamicInput">
Datum 1<br><input type="text" name="dates[]">
</div>
<input type="button" value="dodaj" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
```

*this is in: /administrator/components/com_k2/views/item/tmpl/default.php*

In K2.js I dynamicly add fields.

How do i now send data to database?

I am not that good at joomla, i have written this, but is not working.. can you help me.

```
$dates = array();
$dates = JRequest::getVar('dates', NULL, 'POST', 'array');
foreach ($dates as $key=>$value) {
$object = new JObject;
$object->set('datum', $value);
unset($object->_errors);
$datumi[] = $object;
}
$query = "INSERT INTO #__k2_items (`dates`) VALUES (NULL, $datumi)";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

*This is in: /administrator/components/com_k2/models/item.php*

Comment: no, I just get NULL in databse

Comment: I tried with only one value but I get the same result (NULL).

Comment: in joomla i get rederected when i press save. Is it possible that i dont get data from form to php on 'post'?

Comment: I'd like to see what `echo $query` shows.

Answer (score 0):

$dates = JRequest::getVar('dates', NULL, 'POST', 'array');

where it says NULL , it should be default value

http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest::getVar

your query should wait for the action, seems like it is being executed on item view

you need to place your code inside a function

```
function preuzmiDatum(){

$dates = array();
$dates = JRequest::getVar('dates','default value','post');
foreach ($dates as $key=>$value) {
$object = new JObject;
$object->set('datum', $value);
unset($object->_errors);
$datumi[] = $object;
}
$query = "INSERT INTO #__k2_items (`dates`) VALUES (NULL, $datumi)";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query(); 


}
```

in models/item.php and call that function on form action

Comment: i still cann't get this to work.I got Fatal error: Call to undefined function preuzmiDatum().. i put function in the file an call it at case save...  I'm getting frustrated.. Can some one do this for me :) ?

Comment: Did i put the code to the wrong place in joomla k2 component, so that maybe the code doesn't get data from form?

Comment: i have managed to put one value in database, but i need help with array .. Below i working code for one value:
    $dates = JRequest::getVar('dates', NULL, 'POST');
    if( isset($dates)) {
      $datumi = new JObject;
      $datumi->set('datum', $dates);
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO #__k2_items (`dates`) VALUES ($datumi)";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();

Comment: You removed the null parameter like I told you. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me this topic is kind of closed, but I would like to know if was there any solution for the problem?

I have a similar issue. I found out the problem is that k2 component doesn't see the submitted values.

To be sure about this, I used GET method, so I could see the submitted values in the adress line. However I also placed an

> echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

line in the item.php but echoed only the base uri which is frustrating. I saw domain.com/article_title?mysubmittedvalue=value&etc in the browser's adress line,
and only domain.com/article_title on the page.

Of course the form is all right, since in the adress line you can find the submitted values. The problem is somewhere in the k2 component.

ALSO trying with this code:

> ```
> JURI::getInstance()->toString();
> ```

which is the appropiate joomla way to get the full URI
http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/toString

Comment: Yes I solved the problem with moving the whole idea to another platform. So I created website using MODX - it allows me more freedom in desgin and code... :)